# How to select a certain digit of a double number in MQL4/MQL5

Tags: function, mql4, mql5

i'm trying to write a function for round the last digits of an asset to the TICKSIZE.

Example:
Input: 1256,57
TickSize: 0.05

I want to force the input price to 1256,55 or 1256.60
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the price by the tick size. Round your answer to a whole number, multiply this by your tick size. Easy!

```
Comment("Modified price is ",double(int(Bid/0.05))*0.05);
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted, thanks.